# Nonstandard exponential generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

Exponential generating functions have an $n!$ in the denominator.

Does anyone have references to generating functions with an $n^n$ in the denominator?

Comment: There are no known closed-form functions, either special or elementary, whose series expansion has $n^n$ anyhwere in it.

Comment: See [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream), [OEIS A$073009$](http://oeis.org/A073009), and [OEIS A$094082$](http://oeis.org/A094082), as well as [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145289) question.